# Prevent click a link if dragged

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stop click events if dragged.

I think the simplest version of this is dragging yourself. Basically IF the user presses down, then moves, then releases I don't want a click event.
this is the script

```
const tabsBox = document.querySelector('.kemem'),
  allTabs = tabsBox.querySelectorAll('.pop-post'),
  arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-mem svg')

let isDragging = false

const handleIcons = scrollVal => {
  let maxScrollableWidth = tabsBox.scrollWidth - tabsBox.clientWidth
  arrowIcons[0].parentElement.style.display = scrollVal <= 0 ? 'none' : 'flex'
  arrowIcons[1].parentElement.style.display =
    maxScrollableWidth - scrollVal <= 1 ? 'none' : 'flex'
}

arrowIcons.forEach(icon => {
  icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // if clicked icon is left, reduce 350 from tabsBox scrollLeft else add
    let scrollWidth = (tabsBox.scrollLeft += icon.id === 'left' ? -340 : 340)
    handleIcons(scrollWidth)
  })
})

allTabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
    tabsBox.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
    tab.classList.add('active')
  })
})

const dragging = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (!isDragging) return
  tabsBox.classList.add('dragging')
  tabsBox.scrollLeft -= e.movementX
  handleIcons(tabsBox.scrollLeft)
}

const dragStop = () => {
  isDragging = false
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  tabsBox.classList.remove('dragging')
}

tabsBox.addEventListener('mousedown', () => (isDragging = true))
tabsBox.addEventListener('mousemove', dragging)
document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop)
```

```
    <div class='icon-mem lefto'><div class='overflow-left'></div><svg aria-hidden='true' class='jt-icon' id='left'><use xlink:href='#i-arrow-l'></use></svg></div>
      <ul class="kemem">
        <li class="pop-list">Programming</li>
        <li class="pop-list">HTML</li>
        <li class="pop-list">CSS</li>
        <li class="pop-list">Python</li>
      </ul>
    <div class='icon-mem righto'><div class='overflow-right'></div><svg aria-hidden='true' class='jt-icon' id='right'><use xlink:href='#i-arrow-r'></use></svg></div>
```

this is the demo : [demo](https://www.8cara.com)

Am I missing a simpler solution?

Comment: "if dragged." Can you elaborate this further?

Comment: It would be helpful to narrow down your code to the simplest possible example, instead of dumping everything

Answer (score 1):

You can add and remove a click event that prevents other click events from happening when you stop dragging.

```
function preventClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

const dragStop = (e) => {
  if(isDragging) e.target.addEventListener("click", preventClick);
  else e.target.removeEventListener("click", preventClick)
  isDragging = false
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  tabsBox.classList.remove('dragging')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to record the initial and the ending state of the 'pointer'. Attach a property on the element (`_initX`) and compare that during 'click' event. If sufficiently close (within epsilon range), then fire the event otherwise suppress. One thing that kept my attention is that, if I substitued 'click' with 'pointerup', I was not able to suppress the behavior on the link in some browsers. 'click' seems to get the job done both in mobile and web browser.

```js
const a = document.getElementsByTagName("A")[0],
      epsilon = 10e-1;
a.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e){
  a._initX = e.clientX; //record the position
})
document.documentElement.addEventListener("pointermove", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //many browsers will cancel opening links if dragged, so suppress that :)
})
a.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if (isNaN(a._initX)){return}
  if (
    e.clientX > a._initX - epsilon &&
    e.clientX < a._initX + epsilon
  ) {/*No drag, so links will fire*/} else {
    //drag detected, suppress the link
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  a._initX = NaN;
})
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: Gray;
  border-radius: 2px solid gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```